# vaadin.urlMapping frontend resources

Tags: url, static, mapping, resources, vaadin

I'm trying to move my Vaadin 23.2.17 application to a different urlMapping. I'm using Spring Boot security and all seems to work well, I've followed the documentation for example configuring the application.properties parameter

vaadin.urlMapping = /vaadin/*

the application starts on the new context and I've also registered a new VaadinServlet in my Application class as follows:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean frontendServletBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new VaadinServlet() {
        @Override
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            if (!serveStaticOrWebJarRequest(req, resp)) {
                resp.sendError(404);
            }
        }
    }, "/vaadin/frontend/*");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
}
```

Despite that it seems the application is not able to read the static content from the frontend/images directory. For example I've in my code:

```
    Image image = new Image("images/company-logo.gif", "company-logo");
    portalLogo.add(image);
```

but that image is not displayed as it's not found.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you shift Vaadin out of the root, it's your job to serve the static
resources:

> `VaadinServlet` handles static resource requests, if you have mapped it
> to `/*`. If not, the servlet container takes care of static resource
> requests.
>
> ---
>
> Source:
> https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/advanced/loading-resources/#static-resources

Since you usually don't want to change all your references in the code,
the easiest way with SpringBoot is to put the resource under:

```
src/main/resources/static/
```

E.g. your file:

```
src/main/resources/static/images/company-logo.gif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've solved by putting the static content in

scr/main/resources/static/< urlMapping >/images folder